# Cannot get java to work inside an amd64 docker image emulated on an arm64/v8 orange pi 5

Tags: docker, ubuntu, arm64, orange-pi

I m working on a Jenkins test station inside an orange pi 5 which will wait for a pull request to try and pass some tests on a stm32 abstraction library. The problem I have is that the IDE's for stm32 programming don t seem to work on arm64 based architectures (which I find ridicule, they whole purpose is programming for arm64 architectures and they don t work on these)

As it seems that i cannot work with arm64 infrastructure (as i need to compile the library and tests so they can be send to a stm32 board via ethernet using a bootloader) i decided to use docker to emulate an amd64 architecture in a container, with the help of tonistiigi/binfmt and ubuntu 22.04 images, so i can at last compile the stm32 projects without having to make cross compiling on cmake.

I wanted to emulate a amd64 ubuntu image with stm32cubeIDE in a container of docker inside my orange pi 5, for the purpose of compiling stm32 projects on it.

The only problem is that java doesn t seem to work in any version, not jdk nor jre (which would work as i only need java to run stm32cubeIDE and jenkins, not to develop on it), not java 11 nor 8 or 17. The simplest most repeatable error I get is on the installation of java and running java -version.

The whole set up is like this (on a orange pi 5 sh ubuntu arm64/v8 enviroment with docker installed no images and internet connection):

```
sudo docker run --privileged --rm tonistiigi/binfmt --install amd64 
sudo docker run -it -p 8080:80 --rm --platform linux/amd64 ubuntu
```

//now you should be inside of the emulated amd64 ubuntu container. Inside there:
`apt-get update apt-get install default-jdk Y`

//confirm that you want to download it. This will install a bunch of things, most of them dependencies for java to work. When java at last gets to be installed, it throws three fatal errors:

```
Setting up default-jre-headless (2:1.11-72build2) ...
Setting up openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 (11.0.18+10-0ubuntu1\~22.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jjs to provide /usr/bin/jjs (jjs) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool to provide /usr/bin/keytool (keytool) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmid to provide /usr/bin/rmid (rmid) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmiregistry to provide /usr/bin/rmiregistry (rmiregistry) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/pack200 to provide /usr/bin/pack200 (pack200) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/unpack200 to provide /usr/bin/unpack200 (unpack200) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jexec to provide /usr/bin/jexec (jexec) in auto mode
Aborted (core dumped)

 

 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000004002ed0229, pid=9440, tid=9443

 JRE version:  (11.0.18+10) (build )

 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.18+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, interpreted mode, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)

 Problematic frame:

 V  \[libjvm.so+0x42e229\]

 Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to //core.9440)

 An error report file with more information is saved as:

 //hs_err_pid9440.log


ignoring dump failure
```

- 

```
Setting up ca-certificates-java (20190909ubuntu1.1) ...
head: cannot open '/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts' for reading: No such file or directory

 

 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 

 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000004002f01229, pid=9602, tid=9605

 

 JRE version:  (11.0.18+10) (build )

 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.18+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)

 Problematic frame:

 V  \[libjvm.so+0x42e229\]

 

 Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to //core.9602)

 

 An error report file with more information is saved as:

 //hs_err_pid9602.log

 

 

/var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst: line 80:  9600 Done                    echo -e "-diginotar_root_ca\\n-diginotar_root_ca_pem"
9602 Aborted                 (core dumped) | java -Xmx64m -jar $JAR -storepass "$storepass"
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates-java (--configure):
installed ca-certificates-java package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134\`





Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d... 

 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000004002f03229, pid=11451, tid=11454

 JRE version:  (11.0.18+10) (build )

 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.18+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)

 Problematic frame:

 V  \[libjvm.so+0x42e229\]

 Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /etc/ssl/certs/core.11451)

 
 An error report file with more information is saved as:

 /etc/ssl/certs/hs_err_pid11451.log

 

 

Aborted (core dumped)
E: /etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore exited with code 1.
done.
Errors were encountered while processing:
ca-certificates-java
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)\`
```

It seems that the certificates are screwing me up. When I try to use java for anything:

```
\`java -version

 
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 

 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000004002ed2229, pid=11472, tid=11475

 

 JRE version:  (11.0.18+10) (build )

 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.18+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)

 Problematic frame:

 V  \[libjvm.so+0x42e229\]

 

 Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to //core.11472)

 

 An error report file with more information is saved as:

 //hs_err_pid11472.log

 

 

Aborted (core dumped)\`
```

The same happens if i use the jdk and jre deb and generic installers form java web page instead of using apt-get, and it also happens with the stm32cubeIDE jre intrinsec version.

git, python3, and even nautilus seem to work perfectly and i did install the amd64 version there so it is emulating right except for java. Is it something i messed up? Is the arm64/v8 version that doesn t work with tonistiigi/binfmt image? or is it on the java end? I cannot undestand these core dumps so i cannot get what i m doing wrong.